# App doesn't display suggestion while framing a post

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app, ios-app

Stack Overflow usually displays suggestions when a post is being framed. But this does not happen in the Android app. I am using the latest version of the app. It didn't display any suggestions even when I was framing this post (using app).

Whenever I post a question through the app, I am not able to confirm if it could be a duplicate question since no suggestion is shown. If it happens to be a duplicate then it's badly received by the community. Please take this into consideration. I have noticed that no sites in Stack Exchange network displays suggestions when posting via the app.